# Any tips for a more pythonic way to implement state machine behavior?

Tags: python, state

For brevity, I'm just showing what can/must occur in states.  I haven't run into any oddities in the state machine framework itself.

**Here is a specific question:**

Do you find it confusing that we have to **return** `StateChange(...)` and `StateMachineComplete(...)` whereas some of the of the other actions like `some_action_1(...)` and `some_action_2(...)` need not be returned - they're just direct method invocations?

I think that `StateChange(...)` needs to return because otherwise code beyond the `StateChange(...)` call will be executed.  This isn't how a state machine should work!  For example see the implementation of `event1` in the ExampleState below

```
import abc

class State(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):

    # =====================================================================
    # == events the state optionally or must implement ====================
    # =====================================================================

    # optional: called when the state becomes active.
    def on_state_entry(self): pass

    # optional: called when we're about to transition away from this state.
    def on_state_exit(self): pass

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def event1(self,x,y,z): pass

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def event2(self,a,b): pass

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def event3(self): pass

    # =====================================================================
    # == actions the state may invoke =====================================
    # =====================================================================

    def some_action_1(self,c,d,e):
        # implementation omitted for brevity
        pass

    def some_action_2(self,f):
        # implementation omitted for brevity
        pass

class StateChange:

    def __init__(self,new_state_type):
        # implementation omitted for brevity
        pass

class StateMachineComplete: pass

class ExampleState(State):

    def on_state_entry(self):
        some_action_1("foo","bar","baz")

    def event1(self,x,y,z):

        if x == "asdf":
            return StateChange(ExampleState2)
        else:
            return StateChange(ExampleState3)

        print("I think it would be confusing if we ever got here.  Therefore the StateChange calls above are return")

    def event2(self,a,b):

        if a == "asdf":
            return StateMachineComplete()

        print("As with the event above, the return above makes it clear that we'll never get here.")

    def event3(self):

        # Notice that we're not leaving the state.  Therefore this can just be a method call, nothing need be returned.
        self.some_action_1("x","y","z")

        # In fact we might need to do a few things here.  Therefore a return call again doesn't make sense.
        self.some_action_2("z")

    # Notice we don't implement on_state_exit().  This state doesn't care about that.
```

Answer (score 4):

When I need a state machine in Python, I store it as a dictionary of functions. The indices into the dictionary are the current states, and the functions do what they need to and return the next state (which may be the same state) and outputs. Turning the crank on the machine is simply:

```
state, outputs = machine_states[state](inputs)
```

Answer (score 1):

By putting the outgoing state changes in code you're obfuscating the whole process.  A state machine should be driven by a simple set of tables.  One axis is the current state, and the other is the possible events.  You have two or three tables:

1. The "next-state" table that determines the exit state
2. The "action" table that determines what action to take
3. The "read" table that determines whether you stay on the current input event or move on to the next.

The third table may or may not be needed depending on the complexity of the input "grammar".

There are more esoteric variations, but I've never found a need for more than this.

Comment: [Entry and exit actions mentioned in this article on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UML_state_machine#Entry_and_exit_actions) discusses the pro's and con's of using entry and exit actions.  They're clearly recognized in Moore Machines but depending on the application in question they may add or remove value.

Comment: I think the pattern where they'd be useful is if one state can lead to a number of other states and before or after these transitions, the same action must occur.  So the action could be duplicated as an entry action to be performed on the various states or as an exit action on just the one state.

Answer (score 0):

I also struggled to find a good state_machine solution in python.  So I wrote [state_machine](https://github.com/jtushman/state_machine)

It works like the following

```
@acts_as_state_machine
class Person():
    name = 'Billy'

    sleeping = State(initial=True)
    running = State()
    cleaning = State()

    run = Event(from_states=sleeping, to_state=running)
    cleanup = Event(from_states=running, to_state=cleaning)
    sleep = Event(from_states=(running, cleaning), to_state=sleeping)

    @before('sleep')
    def do_one_thing(self):
        print "{} is sleepy".format(self.name)

    @before('sleep')
    def do_another_thing(self):
        print "{} is REALLY sleepy".format(self.name)

    @after('sleep')
    def snore(self):
        print "Zzzzzzzzzzzz"

    @after('sleep')
    def big_snore(self):
        print "Zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz"

person = Person()
print person.current_state == person.sleeping       # True
print person.is_sleeping                            # True
print person.is_running                             # False
person.run()
print person.is_running                             # True
person.sleep()

# Billy is sleepy
# Billy is REALLY sleepy
# Zzzzzzzzzzzz
# Zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz

print person.is_sleeping                            # True
```